# dialyxir mix task to create PLT exits without error or creating table

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, dialyzer

I am trying to use dialyxir to run dialyzer analysis on my project through the mix tasks it provides.

I have added it to my dependencies and compiled as per the README.

When I run the `mix dialyxir.plt` it reports no error and yet exits without creating the table.

```
$ mix dialyzer.plt
Starting PLT Core Build ... this will take awhile
dialyzer --build_plt --output_plt /home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt --apps erts kernel stdlib crypto public_key -r /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../eex/ebin /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../elixir/ebin /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../ex_unit/ebin /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../iex/ebin /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../logger/ebin /usr/local/lib/elixir/bin/../lib/elixir/../mix/ebin
Creating PLT /home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt ...

# later

$ ll /home/vagrant
# No file called /home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt

# running the mix task errors as expected with no plt

$ mix dialyzer
dialyzer --no_check_plt --plt /home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt -Wunmatched_returns -Werror_handling -Wrace_conditions -Wunderspecs /vagrant/_build/dev/lib/ace/ebin

dialyzer: No such file, directory or application: "/home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt"
```

The question is how do i debug this?

Comment: What happens if you manually run the `dialyzer` command printed in the 3rd line of your snippet?

Comment: It prints `Creating PLT /home/vagrant/.dialyxir_core_19_1.3.2.plt ...Killed` but no further information

Comment: I'd insure that the user you're running mix under can write to the /home/vagrant directory.  Try something like `touch /home/vagrant`

Comment: Ah, "Killed".. does the system you're running this on have limited RAM? That looks like Linux's OOM killer killing the process for using too much RAM.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci No problem with the permissions. It is faily low on RAM. the machine reports it can see 489MiB

Comment: Try giving it 1 or 2GB. IIRC dialyzer PLT creation is quite memory intensive.

Comment: yep that did it. cheers

Answer (score 4):

Like you mentioned in the comments, the complete error message when running `dialyzer` directly included the text `Killed` at the end. That's Linux's Out-of-memory killer killing the process for using too much resources (most likely RAM/swap) since the VM only had ~489MiB of RAM. `dialyzer`'s PLT creation is pretty CPU/memory intensive, so increasing the RAM (to say 1 or 2GB) should fix this.

Answer (score 2):

```
mix dialyzer --plt
```

Command line option `mix dialyxir.plt` returns error as of [dialyxir 0.4.3](https://hex.pm/packages/dialyxir/0.4.3). Dot syntax replaced by flag added above.

**References:**

- [Issue Comment 271126643](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir/issues/60#issuecomment-271126643)
- [Command line options](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#command-line-options)

Comment: `dialyxir` can be [installed globally as an archive](https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir#installation).

Comment: Thank's noobrinja.