# mix phoenix.server (startup) > killed (phoenix server does not start)

Tags: installation, runtime-error, phoenix-framework, elixir

### Situation:

When attempting to start a brand new `phoenix` project on Ubuntu Server 
with the command `mix phoenix.server`
we see the following output:

```
==> mime
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Killed
```

The server fails to start but gives us *no* indication of *why*...
The commands that *preceded* this were:

### Installation of Erlang/Elixir/Phoenix on Ubuntu Server

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential erlang elixir erlang-base-hipe erlang-dev
mix local.hex
mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phoenix_new.ez
```

> Did I miss a step here? (*was I supposed to install anything `else`?*)

### Phoenix Project Creation

```
mix phoenix.new --no-ecto --no-brunch phoenix_app
* creating phoenix_app/config/config.exs
* ...

Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] Y
* running mix deps.get
* ...

cd phoenix_app
mix phoenix.server
```

### Server Details

- Phoenix v1.2.1
- IEx (Elixir) 1.4.2
- Mix 1.4.2
- Erlang/OTP 19
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Host: Digital Ocean

Just trying to figure out if this is an *environment* setup issue or if I have done something wrong. Hoping someone `else` has come across this `Killed` thing before and can help! Unable to find it in the Phoenix docs ...

*iRealise* this is a "*noob*" question, the *context* is I'm trying to do a deployment from scratch using Distillery following these [instructions](http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2016-10-06-elixir-phoenix-distillery), but can't get past the basics so wondering if this `killed` issue is a *thing*...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854839/dialyxir-mix-task-to-create-plt-exits-without-error-or-creating-table/39893846#39893846

Comment: Can you try increasing the RAM temporarily and then compiling? Definitely looks like an OOM issue like my answer above.

Comment: thanks @Dogbert what would we do without you?! :-)

Comment: @Dogbert was 100% correct (_as usual_) on a 512Mb VM only 12MB was free (_thanks Docker for hogging resources it wasn't using!_) shut down docker temporarily to do the compilation step and re-started. all worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing noob question here. Just in case someone read this page and want to know how to properly setup phoenix framework development, here are the installation guide:

Installation in Ubuntu 20.04 + Phoenix 1.5.1:

https://www.yodiw.com/install-elixir-phoenix-framework-in-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/

Installation in Windows 10 + Phoenix 1.5.1:

https://www.yodiw.com/phoenix-elixir-installation-in-windows-10/